# Returning multiple values in if/else statement for Java

Tags: java

I'm having a really hard time understanding how to exactly return a value based on multiple situations. If I choose to have `return kg;` from my `readWeight()` method, outside of the if statements, an error tells me that `kg` may have not been initialized. Isn't it initialized in my if statements? Could someone tell me exactly what I'm doing wrong? I really want to understand this. Thanks everyone, I really appreciate it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double kg = readWeight();
    System.out.println("Your dog weighs" + kg) ;
    System.out.println("Completed computing Kay9 Kibbles amount.") ;
}//end of main method

public static double convertLBtoKG(double lb) {
    final double KG_TO_LB_CONVERSION = 0.454 ;
    double kg = lb * KG_TO_LB_CONVERSION ;
    return kg ;
}//end of convertLBtoKG method

public static double readWeight(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    System.out.println("Would you like to enter your dog's weight " +
                       "in kilograms (kg) or pounds (lb)?\n" +
                       "Enter k (for kg) or p (for lb):") ;
    char weight = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0) ; 
    double lb;
    double kg;

    if(weight == 'p' ){
        System.out.println("Enter your dog's weight in lb:") ;
        lb = keyboard.nextDouble() ;
        kg = convertLBtoKG(lb) ;
    }

    else if(weight == 'k'){
        System.out.println("Enter your dog's weight in kg:") ;
        kg = keyboard.nextDouble() ;
    }

    else if(weight != 'p' && weight != 'k'){
        System.out.println("I can't understand your choice; assuming kilograms.") ;
        System.out.println("Enter your dog's weight in kg:") ;
        kg = keyboard.nextDouble() ;
    }
    return kg ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply initialize it to some default value :

```
double kg = 0.0;
```

A local variable must be initialized, and even though it looks like at least one of the if statements will always be true, and `kg` would be initialized within the respective block, the compiler might not be smart enough to realize that.

Another option that might work is to replace your last "else if" with "else".

Comment: A third option: remove `kg` altogether from that routine ;)

Comment: Or replace the last `else if` by `else`

Comment: @Jongware Well, if you simply replace each `kg = ...` with `return ...` the compiler might complain that not all execution paths return a value.

Comment: @JBNizet That's true. I already mentioned that in the last line.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, also remove the final `else if`. As you already said, it's an effectively redundant test, since both options are already tested earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically

```
if (c1) {
    kg = ...
}
else if (c2) {
    kg = ...
}
else if (c3) {
    kg = ...
}
return kg;
```

So, if neither `c1`, nor `c2`, nor `c3` is true, `kg` is never initialized. You need to make sure that every possible path ensures that `kg` is initialized. Your third `else if` clause is supposed to cover the cases not covered by the two first conditions. So, writing

```
 else if(weight != 'p' && weight != 'k') {
```

is redundant, and the compiler doesn't know that it covers all the remaining cases. The only way for it to know that it covers all the remaning cases is to use

```
else {
```